# XSLT grouping into header & positions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml export available:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <header>
        <creation-date>2022-08-09T08:46:00</creation-date>
        <SequenceOfDocument>10</SequenceOfDocument>
    </header>
    <businessobjects>
        <Reservation>
            <BeginDateTime>2022-07-29T16:00:00</BeginDateTime>
            <OrderNumber>606.00</OrderNumber>
            <Person>
                <UsrAddress>
                    <Code>0393</Code>
                </UsrAddress>
            </Person>
            <TotalActualCostExclVAT>30.00</TotalActualCostExclVAT>
            <ParentOrderRef/>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation>
            <BeginDateTime>2022-07-29T16:00:00</BeginDateTime>
            <OrderNumber>606.01</OrderNumber>
            <RefBODefinitionUserDefined>UsrReservationEquipment</RefBODefinitionUserDefined>
            <Person>
                <UsrAddress>
                    <Code>0393</Code>
                </UsrAddress>
            </Person>
            <TotalActualCostExclVAT>40.00</TotalActualCostExclVAT>
            <ParentOrderRef>606.00</ParentOrderRef>
        </Reservation>
        
        <Reservation>
            <BeginDateTime>2022-07-29T16:00:00</BeginDateTime>
            <OrderNumber>607.00</OrderNumber>
            <RefBODefinitionUserDefined>UsrReservationEquipment</RefBODefinitionUserDefined>
            <Person>
                <UsrAddress>
                    <Code>0500</Code>
                </UsrAddress>
            </Person>
            <TotalActualCostExclVAT>50.00</TotalActualCostExclVAT>
            <ParentOrderRef></ParentOrderRef>
        </Reservation>
    </businessobjects>
</document>
```

And I want to go though all  via XSLT, grouped by: /Person/UsrAddress/Code

The result should be:

```
<SalesOrderHeader>
    <SalesOrderHeaderFields>
        <CustomerNumber>0393</CustomerNumber>
    </SalesOrderHeaderFields>
    <ItemFields>
        <_USERFIELD1>606.00</_USERFIELD1>
    </ItemFields>
    <ItemFields>
        <_USERFIELD1>606.01</_USERFIELD1>
    </ItemFields>
</SalesOrderHeader>

<SalesOrderHeader>
    <SalesOrderHeaderFields>
        <CustomerNumber>0500</CustomerNumber>
    </SalesOrderHeaderFields>
    <ItemFields>
        <_USERFIELD1>607.00</_USERFIELD1>
    </ItemFields>
</SalesOrderHeader>
```

I tried already:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Reservation" group-by="/Person/UsrAddress/Code">

                      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
```

But I don't get them grouped by Person/UsrAddress/Code. I Don't get them grouped like in the example. Maybe someone can give me an hint?

Comment: Your paths are off, start with an example/introduction like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info, then adapt a group-by sample to your needs, making sure you use relative paths where necessary. If you continue to get stuck, post a minimal but comple XSLT and the error or wrong output you get.

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select="Reservation" group-by="/Person/UsrAddress/Code">` try `<xsl:for-each-group select="Reservation" group-by="Person/UsrAddress/Code">`.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two solutions, one using `XSLT 1.0` and the other using `XSLT 2.0` *based on your tag*.

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

Using the [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) instruction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="//document">
          <!-- Create SalesOrderHeader/SalesOrderHeaderFields/CustomerNumnber elements based on unique Person/UsrAddress/Code values -->
          <xsl:for-each-group select="businessobjects/Reservation" group-by="Person/UsrAddress/Code">
            <xsl:element name="SalesOrderHeader">
                <xsl:element name="SalesOrderHeaderFields">
                    <xsl:element name="CustomerNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- Create ItemFields/_USERFIELD1 elements grouped by Person/UsrAddress/Code values -->
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:element name="ItemFields">
                        <xsl:element name="_USERFIELD1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See **[2.0 Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmsLAD)**.

### XSLT 1.0 Solution

Using the [Muenchien Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) of grouping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Create Key based on the Code element -->
    <xsl:key name="unique-codes" match="//Reservation" use="Person/UsrAddress/Code" />
    <xsl:template match="//document">
        <!-- Create SalesOrderHeader/SalesOrderHeaderFields/CustomerNumnber elements based on unique Code values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//Reservation[count(. | key('unique-codes', Person/UsrAddress/Code)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="Code" />
            <xsl:element name="SalesOrderHeader">
                <xsl:element name="SalesOrderHeaderFields">
                    <xsl:element name="CustomerNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Person/UsrAddress/Code"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- Create ItemFields/_USERFIELD1 elements grouped by unique Code values -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('unique-codes', Person/UsrAddress/Code)">
                    <xsl:sort select="Code" />
                    <xsl:element name="ItemFields">
                        <xsl:element name="_USERFIELD1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See **[1.0 Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UDF)**.

Worth noting, to make it valid `XML`, you'll need a root tag to wrap it in (i.e. `<SalesOrders>`) *not included in my above solutions*, like this:

```
<SalesOrders>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
        <SalesOrderHeaderFields>
            <CustomerNumber>0393</CustomerNumber>
        </SalesOrderHeaderFields>
        <ItemFields>
            <_USERFIELD1>606.00</_USERFIELD1>
        </ItemFields>
        <ItemFields>
            <_USERFIELD1>606.01</_USERFIELD1>
        </ItemFields>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
        <SalesOrderHeaderFields>
            <CustomerNumber>0500</CustomerNumber>
        </SalesOrderHeaderFields>
        <ItemFields>
            <_USERFIELD1>607.00</_USERFIELD1>
        </ItemFields>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
</SalesOrders>
```

Comment: Not sure what's the point in posting an XSLT 1.0 solution when OP can use XSLT 2.0. More importantly, it's not even a good XSLT 1.0 solution - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I missed the 2.0 tag and thanks for the link. Valid criticism.